# Unity: Accessing .txt files located on Android device connected to PC

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, wear-os

I was wondering if anyone could possibly help me or give some advice on how to access a text file that has been saved onto an Android phone which is connected to a PC using Unity? Basically I am trying to track a player's heart rate using an Android Wear watch (Huawei Watch 2) and then send that data over to my phone (Huawei P10) which is connected to my PC, where it can hopefully be read by Unity. So far I have been able to collect the heart rate data and send it over to my phone where it is saved into a text file in the external storage (in this case storage/emulated/0). My next step is to read the text file in Unity but I am unsure which is the correct way to do this and searching online has not provided any solid leads and I was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction. Apologies if this question is a bit vague and thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to save anything. Just use TCP to send and receive the data

Answer (score 1):

First i would get the path of that text file in my logcat

```
Log.e("PathOfFile",""+filePath);
```

after i get the path of the file i would go to device monitor in Android Studio, and with my phone connected to pc i will go to `storage/emulated/0`

Important Note: `storage/emulated/0` is located into internal memory, so you are not able to see this text from your phone (if no root was made) , but you can see this file in debug mode from Android Studio

[image: This can be found as Device Monitor or Android Monitor]

after that you can navigate to your text file

The reason that the file is stored at internal memory might be because you are creating it into internal memory like this

```
try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to save it in external storage you should do this

```
public File getPublicAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

check the official doc for more info here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#java

happy coding